# Having problems with nested numbered and bulleted list

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Using the LibreOffice Writer, I am formatting a rather long lists of items where **the first level is numbered**, and the most of the numbered items contain **next level items -- with bullets** in the case. The original source is a text with wrong formatting (like plain text mixed with dashes, spaces, tabulators, wrongly applied styles, extra characters...). Sometimes, the parts of the text have to be moved.

I am still in the phase of the raw editing, but I already have the parts where the number list starts from one again. Also, the items seem to use another style (like a different indentation after the number).

I tried to follow the help advice to Ctrl+mark items that are to be renumbered + remove the numbered list + switch on the numbered list. This way the items are renumbered. However, I have, say, 100 items. The approach to select them is error prone, difficult.

Is there any way to tell--**at the place in the text**--that **this numbered item is the next** one numbered **after that item of the same item level**?